# Formatting from Mysql Database into iPhone App

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, formatting

I have created a back end for a website, with different url paramters you can get infos/text out of a mysql database. An iPhone App grabs this text but unfortunately it isn't wwll formatted (line breaks are missing, etc.).

How can I achieve a better formatting?

iPhone app uses **NSISOLatin1StringEncoding**

In the photo, in the section "Artists" there is no line break. So should I replace 
 with \n for the iPhone?[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the best idea to use pre-formatted plain text, especially in a mobile application, but if your app displays text as HTML, you can try something like that:

```
$text = "Your\nText\nWith\nLinebreaks";
// transform your text with a simple function or a more sophisticated regular expression
echo nl2br($text);
```

That will output:

Your
Text
With
Linebreaks

However that might be irrelevant if your app presentation is not HTML-based, so please provide more details if so.

Comment: No, it just grabs the HTML and prints it in the App, no HTML is displayed.

Comment: The problem is on the presentation level and has little to do with DB. If the app yours change it to mind the linebreaks and other necessary formatting. If it's a third party app, read the documentation to learn if it allows formatting at all - maybe there is nothing you can do about that.

Answer (score 0):

How do you pass the text into your app? Via xml? Try encapsulating the text into CData.